# Command-line connection with VPN to remote PostgreSQL fails, other apps work

Tags: vpn, postgresql

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL database hosted on Azure programmatically.
I am able to do so using apps like [PgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org) or [Postico](https://eggerapps.at/postico/). However, the connection does not work with `psql` or `python`. I have the error :

```sh
psql: error: could not connect to server: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

I am using a VPN (GlobalProtect v5.1.5-20) on MacOS 10.15.7. If I turn the VPN off and reboot my computer, the exact same `psql` command does work. Therefore, I don't think it's related to the database server.

My main issue is that I don't know where to look at in order to debug.

What I've done so far:

- Checked the log of Postgres server: can't see my connections attempts.
- Checked `pg_stat_activity` table and can't see any connections from my IP (except the one made with Postico)
- Checked with LittleSnitch whether `python` / `psql` were able to connect to server. It seems that is the case.
- UPDATE: Connecting to Postgres db from a Docker container running locally does work (with or without VPN).

Any thoughts ?

UPDATE 1, my routing tables

- with VPN

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            10.12.24.32        UGSc         utun2       
default            192.168.0.1        UGScI          en0       
10.12.16.1         10.12.24.32        UGHS         utun2       
10.12.24.32        10.12.24.32        UHr          utun2       
10.12.24.32/32     link#18            UCS          utun2       
66.159.218.152     192.168.0.1        UGHS           en0       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#6             UCS            en0      !
169.254.169.254    link#6             UHLSW          en0      !
192.168.0          link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.0.1/32     link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.0.1        f4:6b:ef:4c:94:c4  UHLWIir        en0    946
192.168.0.5        f4:6b:ef:4c:94:c5  UHLWIi         en0    450
192.168.0.10       3c:15:c2:c5:50:4c  UHLWI          en0   1197
192.168.0.13       d4:a3:3d:5d:30:f8  UHLWI          en0    577
192.168.0.22/32    link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.0.24       46:c5:cd:a2:1e:32  UHLWIi         en0   1182
192.168.0.28       8a:a:f8:f7:a2:d4   UHLWI          en0    191
224.0.0/4          link#18            UmCS         utun2       
224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCSI          en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#18            UCS          utun2       
255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCSI           en0      !
```

- without VPN

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGSc           en0       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#6             UCS            en0      !
169.254.169.254    link#6             UHLSW          en0      !
192.168.0          link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.0.1/32     link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.0.1        f4:6b:ef:4c:94:c4  UHLWIir        en0    956
192.168.0.5        f4:6b:ef:4c:94:c5  UHLWIi         en0    460
192.168.0.10       3c:15:c2:c5:50:4c  UHLWI          en0    587
192.168.0.13       d4:a3:3d:5d:30:f8  UHLWI          en0    587
192.168.0.22/32    link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.0.24       46:c5:cd:a2:1e:32  UHLWIi         en0   1192
192.168.0.28       8a:a:f8:f7:a2:d4   UHLWIi         en0    201
224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCS           en0      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCS            en0      !
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `netstat -rn -f inet` when the VPN is turned on and also when it is turned off?

Comment: @jaume Updated the post with routing tables

Comment: Have you tried adding a route with `sudo route add -host <IP address of database server on Azure> 10.12.24.32`? This will direct traffic to your database server through 10.12.24.32, which is the VPN default gateway address. For further troubleshooting, you may want to share the first two decimal numbers of the IP address of your database server, that is, `a.b` if the IP address is `a.b.c.d`.

Comment: I've just tried but it does not work, same error. What is strange though is that connecting via Postico.app or Docker is working fine with or without the VPN. What does not work is trying to connect to the database from the command line if the VPN has been turned on in the same session (i.e. it does not work if the VPN is on or if I've turned on and then off the VPN but it's working if I restart my computer with the VPN turned off)

Comment: @jaume: the IP address of the db is 13.69.c.d

Comment: The routing table is correct and traffic to 13.69 should be sent through the VPN. Things to try: 1) I've been reading some documentation about GlobalProtect and I've noticed that the split tunnel option can be configured based on the application, could it be that PgAdmin/Postico are configured differently than Terminal? 2) The newest version of GlobalProtect seems to be 5.2 with many fixes (see https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/globalprotect/5-2/globalprotect-app-release-notes/gp-app-release-information/globalprotect-addressed-issues.html), could you update and see if that solves the issue?

Comment: Many thanks @jaume for your help ! I will check for the split tunnel option and come back to you. One question though: how could the split tunnel option explain that the terminal connection to PostgreSQL still does not work when the VPN has been turned off ? (and that I need to restart my computer to make it work).

Comment: `how could the split tunnel option explain that the terminal connection to PostgreSQL still does not work when the VPN has been turned off ?` -> I don't have an explanation for that, it may be a bug, it may be a misconfiguration or it may be something else entirely. Let's see if the split tunnel configuration is the culprit...

Comment: Hi @jaume, there is no such thing enabled in GlobalProtect. I was not able to upgrade it, but removing completely for my computer and disabling macOS firewall did not solve the issue. I've tried to install another VPN, Pulse Secure, same issue. It looks like CLI tools "learn" a route and then get puzzled when this route does not exist anymore. Restarting the computer is removing that learned route...

Comment: Thank you coming back to me and trying a Pulse Secure. I really can't say why Terminal behaves like this, but I'm pretty sure you are not the only having this issue, so let's hope someone with more experience with VPN software chimes in.